# Prove that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\ \left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right)$ converges but not absolutely.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to prove that the following series converges but not absolutely:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\ \left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right)$$

I have used the Leibniz test (alternating series test) to prove that the series converges. Now how do I prove it does not converge absolutely?

Comment: What does k run from? $1$ to $\infty$?

Comment: the summation runs from 0 to ∞ @George

Comment: The series diverges. Perhaps you should check the source to see if you have copied it correctly.

Comment: Another simple way of showing divergence of the absolute-value series without telescoping: $(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}) = (k+1)-k = 1$, so $\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}$ $\geq\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k+1}}$.  But now the sum of the latter diverges by comparison with e.g. the harmonic series.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Recall telescoping series

**Answer**: $$\sum_{k=0}^N | (-1)^k \left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k\right) | = - \sum_{k=0}^N \left(\sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k+1} \right) = \\ -\left(\sqrt{0}- \sqrt 1 + \sqrt{1} - \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3} + \dots - \sqrt{N} + \sqrt{N} - \sqrt{N+1}\right) = \sqrt{N+1}, $$

which does not converge as $N\to \infty$.

Comment: not really. Should I just try to write down the first few terms and see where that goes or what do u mean? I'm also not sure what telescoping series means. I am learning this in another language than English so the series may have a different name. Can you please be more specific ?

Comment: Also known as the method of differences. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: I have just checked this online. I don't think I have seen this before. Can u please provide a brief description of the approach ?

Comment: Like you said write out the terms (I would write them down the page). Then you will see cancellation. Like on the wikipedia page: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = 1-\frac{1}{n+1}$ - Notice the $\frac{1}{2}$'s etc cancel out

Comment: alright thanks a lot !